# PHP function is not available in my current PHP Version

Tags: php, polyfills

I would like to use the function **array_key_first** (PHP 7 >= 7.3.0).

My current PHP Version is **7.2**

I use the "Polyfill" as described within the "User Contributed Notes" section of [corresponding PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php)

If I call the **array_key_first** function in my index.php which is where the polyfill is, everything works fine.

If I call the **array_key_first** function within a PHP self-written class, it doesn't work.

How can I define "Polyfills" so that they are "globally" available?

I don't want to define a class method an call it with $this->array_key_first...

I include the following code in my index.php file

```
    if (!function_exists('array_key_first')) {
        function array_key_first(array $array){
            if (count($array)) {
                reset($array);
                return key($array);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Thanks for hints

Comment: share your code with errors in detail.

Comment: Are you using namespaces?

Comment: Tip: https://github.com/symfony/polyfill

Comment: Thanks for the symfony hint. Unfortunately, I can not use this on my shared hosting, so how can set up my code otherwise?

Comment: @MarcWampfler check how the code is written in the Symfony polyfill: https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/blob/master/src/Php55/bootstrap.php and make your owns polyfills in the same way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using a composer-based workflow for including files (which can include files automatically when you first require the autoload.php file), there will only be two ways.

1. Include a file manually to define the function wherever it is used
2. change the `php.ini` file to 'prepend' a file (include a PHP file before the main script runs)

   auto_prepend_file="/path/to/polyfill.php"

If you are on shared hosting, it is unlikely you will be able to change the php.ini file though.

The polyfill defines the function like this:

```
 function array_key_first(array $array) { foreach ($array as $key => $value) { return $key; } }
```

Comment: This is not the same as array_key_first. It will move the array pointer. Array_key_first does not move the position in the array.

Comment: There is a discussion about this on the relevant Polyfill issue. https://github.com/symfony/polyfill/pull/133

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can use array_keys for this.
Array_keys will get all keys in order where [0] is the first.

```
$arr = ["m" => 0,"b" => 1, "k"  => 2,"a" => 3];
$key = array_keys($arr)[0];

echo $key; //m
```

If we look at this example you see that array_keys does not change the position in the array.

It echoes 0 first which is key 0.
Then I move it one step and it echo 1.
Then we do array keys and check again what the position is and it's still 1.
https://3v4l.org/bhoEZ

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have a workaround like so:
$tableArray[key($tableArray)] = array_count_values(reset($tableArray));
But I will use the new function :-)

Comment: @MarcWampfler That moves the array pointer too. Not the same as what you requested.

Answer (score 0):

You can just call `key()`[[1](http://php.net/manual/de/function.key.php)] on the array to retrieve the first key, assuming that the array pointer is currently pointing at the first element, otherwise you would have to call `reset()`[[2](http://php.net/manual/de/function.reset.php)] on it before, e.g:

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
var_dump(key($array));
```

or

```
$array = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2];
reset($array);
var_dump(key($array));
```

https://3v4l.org/ELdhf

> string(1) "a"

Comment: That gives the current position of the array pointer. Not the same as the first key

Comment: @Andreas What? It doesn't, it gives you the key the array pointer is pointing it.

Comment: Yes, but OP asked for the first key, not the current. If it's in the middle of an foreach you can use this, nor your reset method.

Comment: a) You are assuming a context that is not given. b) You can safely use this in a foreach of course. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php *In PHP 7, foreach does not use the internal array pointer.*

Comment: No, OP says: *I would like to use the function **array_key_first*** . reading the manual on said function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php says: *Get the first key of the given array without affecting the internal array pointer.*. I'm not assuming. This is what OP requested

Comment: @Andreas You are assuming that it has to be used inside a foreach. (Which is meaningless since it would work anyways.)

Comment: That doesn't matter. Your reset still does not comply with the function OP requested.